# MercualEclipse : NullPointerException in SyncViewLabelProvider when using version 2.5.0.201804011616

Tags: eclipse, mercurialeclipse

I have just upgraded to MercualEclipse plugin in Eclipse version 2.5.0.201804011616.

When I try to revert a file or perform almost any Mercualaction I get the following error...

[image: Revert File Error]

The .log file contains this...

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2018-04-06 10:04:06.600
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.synchronize.cs.SyncViewLabelProvider$SyncLabelProvider.getChangesetFileOverlay(SyncViewLabelProvider.java:234)
    at com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.synchronize.cs.SyncViewLabelProvider$SyncLabelProvider.getImage(SyncViewLabelProvider.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.team.ui.synchronize.AbstractSynchronizeLabelProvider.getDelegateImage(AbstractSynchronizeLabelProvider.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.team.ui.synchronize.AbstractSynchronizeLabelProvider.getImage(AbstractSynchronizeLabelProvider.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.team.ui.mapping.SynchronizationLabelProvider.getImage(SynchronizationLabelProvider.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.findImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.getColumnImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.getImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorDecoratingLabelProvider$StyledLabelProviderAdapter.getImage(NavigatorDecoratingLabelProvider.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.getImage(DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.getImage(DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.update(DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.update(DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerColumn.refresh(ViewerColumn.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:946)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil.lambda$0(JFaceUtil.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1025)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(StructuredViewer.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil.lambda$0(JFaceUtil.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateItem(StructuredViewer.java:2159)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.internalUpdate(StructuredViewer.java:2142)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.update(StructuredViewer.java:2083)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.update(ColumnViewer.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.update(CommonViewer.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.update(StructuredViewer.java:2027)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleLabelProviderChanged(StructuredViewer.java:1203)
```

Note: I've tested this with a fresh install & workspace for

- eclipse-jee-oxygen-3-win32-x86_64
- eclipse-jee-photon-M6-win32-x86_64

I am using hg.exe version 4.2.1

I have tested with JDK 1.7 and 1.8

Can anyone suggest a fix or workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have released version 2.5.1 in the Experimental Releases category. But first, see the comments [in the issue report](https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/issues/575/npe-when-synchronize).